# Spring не работает и выдаёт ошибку missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven, spring-boot

Начал изучать `Spring`. Создал программу, но при тестовом запуске она выдала следующую ошибку:

```
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

Что с этим делать? Проект основан на `maven`. Файлы классов, лог ошибок и `pom.xml` прикрепляю ниже:

**MavenserverApplication.class:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MavenserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MavenserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**HttpControllerREST.class:**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class HttpControllerREST extends HttpServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (request.getParameter("lastname") != null || request.getParameter("firstname") != null) {
            if (!request.getParameter("lastname").equals("") && !request.getParameter("firstname").equals("")) {
                String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
                String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
                firstname = firstname.substring(0, 1);//Первая буква
                return lastname + " " + firstname + ".";
            } else
                return "No POST data lastname or firstname";
        }
        return "Not POST data ";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.max.mavenserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mavenserver</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

**Лог ошибок:**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Max/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-05-22 21:36:21.116  WARN 6864 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2018-05-22 21:36:21.122  INFO 6864 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-22 21:36:21.128 ERROR 6864 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1231) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1219) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.max.mavenserver.mavenserver.MavenserverApplication.main(MavenserverApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180522.140650-113.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 8 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому что вы используете  `extends HttpServlet`. Поэтому чтобы создать контроллер спрингу нужен `ServletWebServerFactory` который отсутствует.